# How do I tell helm to create internal secrets in namespace

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When trying to run `helm install` to deploy an application to a private K8S cluster, I get the following error:

```
helm install myapp ./myapp
Error: create: failed to create: secrets is forbidden: User "u-user1" 
cannot create resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
exit status 1
```

I know that this is happening because helm creates secrets *behind the scene* to hold information that it needs for managing the deployment.  See [Handling Secrets](https://ibm.github.io/spm-kubernetes/deployment/secrets/):

> As of Helm v3, the release definition is stored as a Kubernetes Secret resource by default, as opposed to a ConfigMap.

The problem is that helm is trying to create the secrets in the default namespace, and I'm working in a private cloud and not allowed to create resources in the default namespace.

**How can I tell helm to use a namespace when creating the internal secrets that it needs to use?**

### Searching for a solution

A search on the helm site found:

- https://helm.sh/docs/faq/ - which says

> In Helm 3, information about a particular release is now stored in the same namespace as the release itself

But I've set the deployment to be in the desired namespace.   My `myapp/templates/deployment.yaml` file has:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: myapp-namespace
```

So I'm not sure how to tell helm to create it's internal secrets in this `myapp-namespace`.

#### Other Searches

- [Helm Charts create secrets in different namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65007977/helm-charts-create-secrets-in-different-namespace) - Is asking a different question about how to create user defined secrets in different namespaces.
- [Helm upgrade is creating multiple secrets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611273/helm-upgrade-is-creating-multiple-secrets) - Different question, and no answer (yet).
- [Secret management in Helm Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638562/secret-management-in-helm-charts) - is asking a different question.

### Update 1)

When searching for a solution I tried adding the `--namespace myapp-namespace` argument to the `helm install` command (see below).

```
helm install --namespace myapp-namespace myapp ./myapp
Error: create: failed to create: secrets is forbidden: User "u-user1" 
cannot create resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "myapp-namespace"
exit status 1
```

Notice that the namespace is now `myapp-namespace`, so I believe that helm is now creating the *internal* secrets in my desired namespace, so I think this answers my original question.

I think I now have a permissions issue that I need to ask the K8S admins to address.

Comment: I believe this is a permissions issue at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the `--namespace` option in order to tell `helm install` what namespace you are using.  The syntax you specified is correct.

```
helm install --namespace myapp-namespace myapp ./myapp
```

You could also put `--namespace` at the end of the command as below:

```
helm install myapp ./myapp --namespace myapp-namespace
```

With this syntax, helm will create the *internal* secrets in the namespace you've specified.

Doing this will prevent the `default` namespace from being polluted.

The following command is then needed to see the install.

```
helm list --namespace myapp-namespace
helm list --all-namespaces
```